# Material from Object not shown when exported in Windows 3d-Viewer

Tags: materials, gltf

So I exported my object in gltf format and when I looked at the object in windows 3D-Viewer it only showed the object but not the material:

[image]

This metallic material is missing:

[image]

I exported it the following way:

[image]

Comment: Is there really any use for windows 3d viewer for us, blenderists?

Comment: I don't feel that this question should have been closed. The linked answer for FBX is five years old and does not reflect current reality, in which most of the Principled BSDF parameters _can_ be exported correctly to glTF, certainly including the simple metallic setup shown here. That said – the appearance of a metallic surface depends heavily on what it is reflecting, if anything. Try the model in a few different glTF viewers. I think it's likely the Windows 3D Viewer just doesn't have very good lighting/environment for a metallic material, but the model itself is fine.

Comment: Agreed, nothing in the old FBX answer explains what's going on here.  I think Don is right that the lighting environment in 3D Viewer isn't ideal for showing off shiny metallic surfaces.  Try [Don's Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) or [Babylon Sandbox](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) instead.

Comment: In Dons viewer everything is fine. But yeah, looks like the texture and ligthing isn't supported in 3D Viewer.